# why python not supporting : while( s = f.readline())?

Tags: python

more example below:

```
 if (a = xyz() ) > abc:
```

Really want to know why, is it kinds of bad smell ?

Note: I know the grammar, but I am asking why Python don't support such grammar as many other language( e.g., c , java...) do supporting

Comment: Ewww, side effects in a boolean test!

Comment: @MartijnPieters: That's pretty much the answer, from the either the docs or a PEP (can't remember which).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does Python assignment not return a value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869770/why-does-python-assignment-not-return-a-value)

Comment: yes it is duplicated, thread close

Comment: @JammyLee: You can 'flag' your own question, then select the 'duplicate' options (there is a menu structure to go through). A moderator will then look at it, as well as signal your post to other users with enough rep to vote to close.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [python design FAQ](http://docs.python.org/faq/design.html#why-can-t-i-use-an-assignment-in-an-expression):

> The reason for not allowing assignment in Python expressions is a common, hard-to-find bug in those other languages, caused by this construct:
>
> ```
>     if (x = 0) {
>         // error handling
>     }
>     else {
>         // code that only works for nonzero x
>     }
> ```
>
> The error is a simple typo: x = 0, which assigns 0 to the variable x, was written while the comparison x == 0 is certainly what was intended.

As explained in the FAQ, most "use cases" for using assignment in an expression can be covered by using iterators instead.

Answer (score 0):

Remember python philosophy : There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.
It doesn't sound obvious to me !
Also you may want to check this answer too : 
[why does python assignment not return a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869770/why-does-python-assignment-not-return-a-value)