# multiple assignments in a sinlge line python as in Java like a=b=c?

Tags: java, python, file, variable-assignment

in Java, this is valid. multiple assignments in a single statement.

```
while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
            }
```

Is there a similar thing  thing in python. I tried but I get the following error.

```
>>> file = open("reverse.py")
>>> while(x=file.readline()!=""):
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    while(x=file.readline()!=""):
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assignment is not an expression in python. Basically while requires an expression and you are giving an statement.

You can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869770/why-does-python-assignment-not-return-a-value) for detailed explanation.

Comment: +10 internets. This is the important point: Assignment is not an expression but a statement, unlike in many other languages.

Comment: Full definition copied from the docs: expr_stmt: testlist_star_expr (augassign (yield_expr|testlist) | ('=' (yield_expr|testlist_star_expr))*)

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such thing.

On the other hand you don't need this kind of syntax with Python. Just iterate over the file object:

```
with open(filename) as fp:
    for line in fp:
        pass
```

Comment: There is such a thing. `a = b = c = 42` is valid, normal and everyday python.

Answer (score 0):

multiple assignments work (though maybe not the way you'd expect):

```
In [373]: a = b = c = 0x1234

In [374]: a
0x1234

In [375]: b
0x1234

In [376]: c
0x1234
```

your problem is the while syntax, which is just while(predicate). assignments can't be part of a predicate in python.

however, most of the time, you don't need those sorts of constructs in python, as they are implicit. you can do:

```
file = open('reverse.py')
for line in file:
    <do something>
```

and it will *automatically* terminate at EOF with StopIteration; you don't need to do the manual sentinel checks. Even more pythonic would be to use a context manager:

```
with open('reverse.py') as file:
    for line in file:
        <do something>
```

which is like the above, but will also *automatically* close the file when you are done.