# Input between print in python

Tags: python, input, python-3.x

Is there anyway to print between two print commands? For example I print `sin(` and `)` and between these parenthesis input amount of `x` for some function like `sin(x)`. Like this:

```
print("sin("
x=float(input())
print(")")
>>sin("""input""")
```

I need to print `sin("` then get input and print the value of `x` then print `)`. To make clear I want to use print and input parallel.

Comment: show the desired output/user experience. this is still unclear as written. do you want to print `sin("` then get input and print the value of `x` then print `)`? Or you want to print the `sin` of `x`? The user has to hit return to get `input` to move on to the rest of the script.

Comment: @beroe I mention  what I want to do. Your turn.

Comment: Still not clear. You want there to be a single print statement capable of printing once then taking input(and store into variable) and then printing? Or do you want that functionality? If the functionality is required then explain what is required that cannot be achieved by 2 print statements and input in between?

Comment: What is the problem you want to solve? This is a case of asking for help with a solution when the problem isn't clear.

Comment: @Burhan Khalid Question edited. Is it clear enough to answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not directly possible because [assignment doesn't return anything in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869770/why-does-python-assignment-not-return-a-value) but with a bit of hack if you really want.

```
def main():
    def f():
        nonlocal x
        x = input()
        return x
    x = ''
    print("Sin(" + f() + ")")
```

This example is an idea about how you can do it. Instead of `nonlocal` you can have other hacks like mutable objects passed directly to give you more control over where you want the value to be stored.

**By mutable objects**

As has been mentioned in comments it is not totally safe and you will need some changes before using this code. It is just meant as an example. Till it becomes clear what the OP actually wants I'll leave it as it is.

```
def main():
    def f(x):
        x[0] = input()
        return x[0]

    x = ['']
    print("Sin(" + f(x) + ")")
```

**EDIT2 - Avoiding echo of newline like in case of input()**

If you want to avoid newline to be echoed then you should see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523174/raw-input-in-python-without-pressing-enter). Then make a function to build the desired input into a nonlocal(or global)  variable as per your requirements. Here you'll have to do some hackery to define another character at which the variable will be built completelty. Then using the function call between two print statements should give you the desired behavior. The variable returned by the function will have to be printed explicitly as nothing will be echoed.

Comment: +1. Nice alternative!

Comment: @Aseem Bansal it's a tricky way but it seems not answering my question   cause python first starts input command then print what is inputed!

Comment: @HamidFzM So you want them to run in parallel? Or print, then input then print? If the latter then the only way I can think of is two print statements and input between these statements.

Comment: @HamidFzM Can you give a practical reason where this could be useful or is it just a trick question?

Comment: Quite ugly to simulate absence of `nonlocal` keyword with mutable method argument this way. Also a bit risky without checking if passed an empty list in `x`.

Comment: @DavidUnric Correct. But as it is still not clear what the OP actually wants I'll leave it as is.

Comment: @Aseem Bansal As you mentioned Could you say how to run in parallel?

Comment: @HamidFzM Don't use things if you don't really need them. I was not able to understand the behavior you wanted and I had started blabbering. If I am correct you want to avoid the echoing of newline on the screen when something is inputted? If yes, it might be possible without external library. I'll take a look.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do that. Each statement has to be done manually:

```
x = float(input())
print("sin(%.2f)"%x)
```

Or if you want the `sin` result:

```
import math
x = math.sin(float(input("Enter X: ")))
print("The sin of X is: {:.2f}".format(x))
```

Edit: added what you want:

As i mentioned, you'll have to print each statement manually:

```
print("sin(", sep="")
#either this
x = float(input())
print(x)
#print(input()) #or just this
print(")")
```

Note the use of two different string formatting method, just to show it. Hope this helps!

Comment: It seems you didn't understand my question I need to input something while I'm printing after my input command!

Comment: @HamidFzM Do you mean "input something in the print command"?

Comment: Yes the exact thing as you mention @Aseem Bansal

Comment: I answered that question, too. The very first line. Except if you do some hackery.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some more concise way - oneliner:

```
print 'sin(%f)=%f' % (lambda x=input(): (x, sin(x)))()
# 1.57
# sin(1.570000)=1.000000
```

Comment: I think he wants to store it in a variable also.

Comment: @AseemBansal If that's what OP asked then this would require two phases - an assignment (it doesn not return a value) and string formatting expression. Not aware of built-in method which mimic such behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

You can't since you can not avoid newline character ath the end of input(). If you really need this, you should use a terminal control library like curses.

[Info from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7174401/2334951)

Comment: I think until now it's the best answer!