# Set variable in loop condition

Tags: python

In Java, I can set a variable in a loop condition as such

```
String s;

while ((s=myFunction())!=null){
    System.out.println("It's there jim. "+s);
}
```

In this example, s would be set to whatever the result of myFunction() was. In Python, I know I can do it as

```
s = myFunction()
while s!=None:
   print "It's there jim",s
   s = myFunction()
```

but I would like to avoid doing this. Is there a way I can do the above Java code in Python?

Comment: what do u mean avoid doing this?

Comment: It's just a nice thing I'm used to in Java. That's all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this in Python. In Java, an assignment `=` is an *expression*, and it evaluates to the value of the assigned variable. In Python, the `=` assignment is an *statement*, so it doesn't have a value (it just gets executed) and can not be used in the way you described (see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869770/why-does-python-assignment-not-return-a-value) for details). Even more, if you try to use an assignment in a place where an expression is expected, you'll get an error:

```
a = 0
(a = 10) + 1
=> SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: @ollien not really, it's a decision decision with other implications, for example: it allows named argument calls where you can say `func(a=0, b=1)` to specify the parameters `a` and `b`.  if assignments were expressions, this wouldn't be doable in an unambiguous way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `iter`:

```
for s in iter(myFunction, None):
    print "It's there jim", s

print s
```

But it's confusing at first glance, so just stick to what you have.

Comment: Okey doke. Thanks for at least giving a solution!