# Unexpected behavior when assigning multiple variables in if() block

Tags: php, variables

In the spirit of seeing [Short-circuit evaluation like Python's "and" while storing results of checks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39603391/2191572) I decided to see how this could be best solved in PHP but I've run into an issue.

**unexpected**

```
<?php
function check_a()
{
    return 'A';
}
function check_b()
{
    return 'B';
}
function check_c()
{
    return 'C';
}

if($a = check_a() && $b = check_b() && $c = check_c())
{
    var_dump($a);
    var_dump($b);
    var_dump($c);
}
```

Results in:

```
bool(true)
bool(true)
string(1) "C"
```

---

**code for what I wanted to happen**

```
<?php
function check_a()
{
    return 'A';
}
function check_b()
{
    return 'B';
}
function check_c()
{
    return 'C';
}

// if(($a = check_a()) && ($b = check_b()) && $c = check_c()) // equivalent to line below
if(($a = check_a()) && ($b = check_b()) && ($c = check_c()))
{
    var_dump($a);
    var_dump($b);
    var_dump($c);
}
```

Results in:

```
string(1) "A"
string(1) "B"
string(1) "C"
```

---

Why does the **unexpected** example act in this way?

Comment: you do realize that you're assigning rather than comparing.

Comment: @Fred-ii- — Isn't that the point of what they are trying to do?

Comment: @Quentin I....er.... guess *lol*. my bad.

Comment: Pretty sure the answer is in http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php … but I don't want to try to unpick it right now to figure out exactly how.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yes I know the difference between `=`, `==`, and `===`. Please try my code and change `check_a()` to `return '';` and you will see what I am asking about

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I made a mistake earlier. However, you mention *"change `check_a()` to `return '';`"* - How is the `return '';` used and where and is it relevant to the question? You didn't post that in your question. However, Quentin and others below have provided you with answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a question of [operator precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php). An [assignment expression returns the assigned value](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php), so you would expect to get `A` and `B` for the first two operations. The reason you're getting boolean `true` instead is that the `&&` operator has a higher precedence than the assignment operator, so in the original expression

```
$a = check_a() && $b = check_b() && $c = check_c()
```

`$a` gets the value of `check_a() && $b = check_b() && $c = check_c()`,

`$b` gets the value of `check_b() && $c = check_c()`,

and `$c` gets the value of `check_c()`.

The expressions `check_a() && $b = check_b() && $c = check_c()`, and `check_b() && $c = check_c()` return boolean `true`, because the use of the `&&` operator causes the expressions to be evaluated as booleans, and all components of the expressions joined by `&&` evaluate to `true`.

To get the results you expect, you can add parentheses as you did, *or* you can use the `and` logical operator instead of `&&`, because it has a lower precedence than the assignment operator.

```
if($a = check_a() and $b = check_b() and $c = check_c()) {
```

Answer (score 2):

The result of a boolean `&&` is a bool! `&&` binds stronger than `=`. Therefore `$b` gets assigned `('B' && $c)` which is a bool... Same obviously with `$a`...