# Using the while loop in Python to retrieve and check the value at the same time

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

When I program using the C++ language, I use the following `while` loop pattern quite often.

```
while ((Data data = GetNewData()) != END) {
  // Do some processing
  ProcessData(data);
}
```

How can we do the same thing in Python? It seems like the following doesn't work.

```
while (data = GetNewData()) != END:
  # Do some processing
  ProcessData(data)
```

Then one alternative I can think of is the following.

```
while 1:
  data = GetNewData()
  if data == END:
    break
  # Do some processing using data
  ProcessData(data)
```

But the above doesn't look neat. Could anyone suggest a good way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python, assignment is a [statement, not an expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869770/why-does-python-assignment-not-return-a-value), which is why

```
while (data = GetNewData()) != END:
    # Do some processing
    ProcessData(data)
```

doesn't work. `(data = GetNewData())` cannot be used as a value.

Instead, you could use [`iter`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#iter):

```
for data in iter(GetNewData, END):
    # Do some processing
    ProcessData(data)
```

The loop will call `GetNewData()` each iteration, and assign the value to `data` unless it is equal to `END`. While this syntax is definitely not as intuitive as the C++ way, it does eliminate bugs where `=` is substituted for `==` and vice versa.