# Define a variable and simultaneously display its content(s)

Tags: python, spyder

I'm new to python and spyder. Is there a way to do something like this(this is something I would do using RStudio):

```
(var<-c(1,2,3,4))
```

This would allow me assign values to my vector while seeing the output at the same time. Is there a `spyder` way to do this?

Comment: Python assignments does not return a value: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869770/why-does-python-assignment-not-return-a-value

Comment: You can combine two lines of statements using a semicolon if you really want: `var = [1,2,3,4];var`