# Why is Python walrus operator (:=) needed instead of just using the normal assignment operator (equal sign)?

Tags: python, variable-assignment, assignment-operator, walrus-operator

I just learned there is a walrus operator in Python 3.8

```py
if a := 2 + 3:
    print(a) # 5
```

I wonder why they created a new operator instead of allowing the existing assignment operator as expression, like

(code that throws a SyntaxError follows)

```py
if a = 2 + 3: # assign 2 + 3 to a, then evaluate the trueness of a
    print(a) # 5
```

Edit: I saw this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50297704/syntax-and-assignment-expressions-what-and-why), but that does not specifically address why we can't use the existing `=` operator in place of `:=`.

Comment:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/4869838/476

Comment: Then you couldn't make more complex conditions like `if (a=2+3) and True:`, because assignment operator doesn't return anything

Comment: @Alexey The assignment operator *could* return something, as it does in most other languages…